# anaconda navigator will no longer start even through cmd, won't install or update or manage environments

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

I'm new to `django` and using the `anaconda cloud environment`. Its been working well for 3 months plus but as of 7-24-2018 it is just stop to launch the navigator or open through cmd. I can't manage environments or install packages. Using the `anaconda prompt` also gives me the same error upon launching. It started when I wanted to install `django-Oscar`, but not having its dependencies I was forced to install the packages manually which in turn needed `cytoolz` that needs `Microsoft Visual C++` build tools which I got to install as well but the error persists. Please help me!

Copy/Paste of CMD Traceback:

> C:\Users\kaukau\Desktop>conda --version conda 4.5.4
>
> C:\Users\kaukau\Desktop>anaconda-navigator Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy__init__.py", line
>   169, in 
>       from PySide import **version** as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line
>   6, in 
>       from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils__init__.py",
>   line 15, in 
>       from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy__init__.py", line
>   175, in 
>       raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found') qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
>
> C:\Users\kaukau\Desktop>conda install qt --force Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 42, in 
>       from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cytoolz__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from .itertoolz import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytoolz.itertoolz'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 819, in **call**
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
>   73, in _main
>       from ..base.context import context   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, LoadError, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\toolz\functoolz.py",
>   line 501
>       f.**name** for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
>       ^ SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 42, in 
>       from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cytoolz__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from .itertoolz import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytoolz.itertoolz'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 10, in
>   
>       sys.exit(main())   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
>   113, in main
>       return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 1112, in conda_exception_handler
>       return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 822, in **call**
>       return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 864, in handle_exception
>       return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 876, in handle_unexpected_exception
>       self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 932, in print_unexpected_error_report
>       from .base.context import context   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, LoadError, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\toolz\functoolz.py",
>   line 501
>       f.**name** for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
>       ^ SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 42, in 
>       from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cytoolz__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from .itertoolz import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytoolz.itertoolz'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
>   97, in main
>       from ..activate import main as activator_main   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line
>   11, in 
>       from .base.context import ROOT_ENV_NAME, context, locate_prefix_by_name   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, LoadError, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\toolz\functoolz.py",
>   line 501
>       f.**name** for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
>       ^ SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 42, in 
>       from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cytoolz__init__.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from .itertoolz import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cytoolz.itertoolz'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 10, in
>   
>       sys.exit(main())   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line
>   110, in main
>       return ExceptionHandler().handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 864, in handle_exception
>       return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 876, in handle_unexpected_exception
>       self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py",
>   line 932, in print_unexpected_error_report
>       from .base.context import context   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, LoadError, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,   File
>   "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from .._vendor.toolz.functoolz import excepts   File "C:\Users\kaukau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_vendor\toolz\functoolz.py",
>   line 501
>       f.**name** for f in reversed((self.first,) + self.funcs),
>       ^ SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized

---

I've just found out that I cant even use any conda commands except the : >conda --version< command only.
Please help me resolve this issue without uninstalling then reinstalling anaconda completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to waste your time, I solved it by reinstalling anaconda completely and every project started working again....thanks to those who read it, the effort is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happen when you directly download and insall anaconda normally form its website.

Updating `anaconda` solved this issue for me in `Manjaro` and will surely work on `Windows` as well.

use `conda update anaconda-navigator` command to Update Anaconda.

If it doesn't starts, restart your pc and try to open it again.